# What probability distribution best describes the place of a dart?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I've been asked to provide a distribution that best describes the place a dart might hit on the dart board. At first glance I though it would be uniform, but that would be true if we were talking about someone throwing it with a blindfold on, then I thought a bivariate normal distribution might do a better job, but I cannot seem to give a reasonable explanation for it.

Comment: I would say:  radius is one-sided normal centered at $0$.  Angle is uniform on $[0,2\pi]$.  Or, equivalently, let the radius be normal centered at $0$ and angle uniform on $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: Your reason would be that they are trying to hit the center and don’t suck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on factors such as precision and accuracy. If the dart is precise but not accurate, you’ll get a bivariate normal but not at the center. If it is precise and accurate, you’ll get a bivariate normal at the center. If it’s accurate but not precise, you could get a bivariate normal with large variance, or a uniform if you wish. The same is with not accurate and not precise—the hits are centered outside the target but have large spread, so could be modeled using a bivariate normal or a uniform.

Comment: Spell checker is your enemy.

Comment: Drats, I wanted to talk about bicarbonate ions.